# How can I use the ShortName property of the Display attribute for my table headers>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I see the `DisplayAttribute` has a `ShortName` property, but I see no `Html.ShortName` helper. How can I get to use this short name for my table column headings? Do I have to write my own helper?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could write your own helper :

Something like

```
public static IHtmlString ShortLabelFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression) {
   var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
   var content = metadata.ShortDisplayName?? metadata.DisplayName ?? /*something else*/ ?? string.Empty;
   return new HtmlString(content);
}
```

But, from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata.shortdisplayname%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) :

> The short display name can be used in a tooltip or in other display
>   contexts such as the title of tabular list views where the complete
>   display name might not fit. For example, in MVC, this name is used in
>   tables where the columns are not wide enough to display the complete
>   field name. If this field is null, DisplayName should be used.

So it looks like it should be automatic (when no room enough), but... untested here. Sounds like it should work with @Html.LabelFor in this way.

Comment: I think "not room enough" is way to broad. By default it just wraps the long name and voila, there is enough room.

Comment: @ProfK well, I also think that it's not automatic at all. So you'll have to go for a custom helper.

Comment: This for the win. plug into 'public static class HtmlHelpers' no namespace. Job done. Remove the 'default comment' - job done. Cheers +1

Comment: does not work "automatic" I have tr th, it doesn't work automatically... And, by the way, how on the server side the code "knows" is there is enought room to display on the client... strange

Answer (score 1):

For me the accepted answer didn't help much because my view model was defined as an IEnumerable:

```cs
@model IEnumerable<Document>
```

And so I needed a DisplayShortNameFor version of the existing extension method:

```cs
public static MvcHtmlString DisplayNameFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<IEnumerable<TModel>> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression);
```

I was able to find one in [here](https://gist.github.com/odrix/4960693):

```cs
public static string DisplayShortNameFor<TModel, TValue>(this global::System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<global::System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TModel>> t, global::System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<global::System.Func<TModel,TValue>> exp)
{
    CustomAttributeNamedArgument? DisplayName = null;
    var prop = exp.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (prop != null)
    {
        var DisplayAttrib = (from c in prop.Member.GetCustomAttributesData()
                             where c.AttributeType == typeof(DisplayAttribute)
                             select c).FirstOrDefault();
        if(DisplayAttrib != null)
            DisplayName = DisplayAttrib.NamedArguments.Where(d => d.MemberName == "ShortName").FirstOrDefault();
    }
    return DisplayName.HasValue ? DisplayName.Value.TypedValue.Value.ToString() : "";
}
```

Not sure if it is the best approach but it worked fine for me.

Comment: Just as a hint, for table, I define e generic `IndexViewModel<T>`, that contains an `IEnumrable<T> Items` as well as in instance of `T HeadersModel`, and then the I use `HeadersModel` in the `THEAD` to define column names.

Then I have `@model `ProductIndexModel<Product>` derived from the base generic, and for the table rows loop through `Model.Items`.

Comment: But, thanks, I may be able to use this with my generic base model as well.