# ShortName in the Display attribute (DataAnnotations)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, data-annotations

Name attribute works proper, but ShortName doesn't work.

```
[Display(Name = "Date of the transfer the task", ShortName = "Trans date")]
public DateTime TransferDate { get; set; }
```

Even when I delete Name attribute, ShortName is ignored ("TransferDate" displays in the column header).

In the view I do this:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TransferDate)
```

Comment: Check out this answer: [How can I use the ShortName property...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14255463/how-can-i-use-the-shortname-property-of-the-display-attribute-for-my-table-heade)

Comment: @scheien Does it mean that it's impossible without writing my own helper? I thought it should be automatic too..

Comment: I guess so according to that post. You are also referencing the `DisplayName` attribute in your view => `@Html.DisplayNameFor(...)`. I'm unaware of any fallbacks to ShortName to be honest :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the Description for the [`ShortName` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.shortname.aspx) on the [`Display` Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.aspx) you'll see that it has a pretty limited scope out of the box:

[image: Short Name Description]

Of course, that doesn't limit you from leveraging that value on your Model Metadata, but there aren't any native helpers that do so.

[Starting with MVC 2](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-2-modelmetadata.html), [`ModelMetadata`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata.aspx) provides two methods to access the underlying data: `FromStringExpression` and `FromLambdaExpression`, so you don't really need to start from scratch in writing your own helper or extension method.

If you *hate* writing HTML helper methods, you can do this all inline:

```cs
@ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<RegisterModel, string>( 
            model => model.TransferDate, ViewData).ShortDisplayName} )
```

But it's also perfectly valid to add an extension method for consistency of access, deduplication of code, and improved error handling

```cs
public static class MvcHtmlHelpers
{
   public static MvcHtmlString ShortNameFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> self, 
           Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
   {
       var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, self.ViewData);
       var name = metadata.ShortDisplayName ?? metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName;

       return MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Format(@"<span>{0}</span>", name));
   }
}
```

And then use like any other helper method:

```cs
@Html.ShortNameFor(model => model.TransferDate)
```

**Further Reading**:

- [How do I display the DisplayAttribute.Description attribute value?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6578828/1366033)
- MVC has long subsisted on custom extension methods, like [needing DisplayNameFor before it was added in MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3885796/1366033)
- See this question for a quick [breakdown of the differences between `[Display(name="")]` vs. `[DisplayName("")]` attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5243665/1366033)
- See this answer for [working with ASP.NET MVC 6 / Core 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35294035/1366033)

Comment: is there any solution for ASP.NET Core?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out to do it in Core too. If anyone know how, would be appreciated!